# HTTP 500 Error runs onSuccess callback in React-Query

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have the below code:

```
const {mutate: revokation, isLoading, isError, error, isSuccess, data}: any = useMutation(() => revokationAPI({
    taxpayerID: taxpayer,
    invoiceID: item?.uuid
}), {
    retry: false,
    onSuccess: (response: any) => {
        queryClient.invalidateQueries(['invoice', taxpayer])
    },
    onError: (err: any) =>{
        ErrorToast(err.response.data.message)
    }
});
```

And here is my Axios API function:

```
export function revokationAPI({taxpayerID, invoiceID}: {taxpayerID: string | undefined; invoiceID: string | undefined;}){
  return axios.post(`something/${taxpayerID}/invoice/revoke/${invoiceID}`)
}
```

[image]

When server returns HTTP 500 error, onSuccess callback runs, I can't figure out what's the issue.

Comment: Can you create an [mre]? A stackblitz link would also be helpful.

Comment: I wanted to create a minimal reproducible example but wondered how can I mimic HTTP 500 error and the behaviour of react-query.

Comment: On stackblitz, you can create a NextJS sandbox and use one of the API routes to create an API returning 500. Then, use react-query on any of the pages to make the API requests.

Comment: could it be that you have a custom axios configuration that instructs axios not to throw for this scenario?

Comment: You are right Anton, it was because of my own axios configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with my axios instance to begin with:

```
 const axiosInstance = axios.create({
      baseURL: config.REACT_APP_API_URL,
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
    
      },
    });     
    
    axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(undefined, function (error) {
        if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
            localStorage.clear()
            axiosInstance.get("/sso/generate-login-route").then((data) => {
                window.location.href = data.data.data.SSO_LOGIN;
                localStorage.clear()
            });
        }else return Promise.reject(error);
    });
```

Then I turned it into this and react-query could handle it:

```
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(undefined, function (error) {
    if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
        localStorage.clear()
        axiosInstance.get("/sso/generate-login-route").then((data) => {
            window.location.href = data.data.data.SSO_LOGIN;
            localStorage.clear()
        });
    } else if(error.response && error.response.status === 500){
        WarningToast('500 Error!')
    }

    return Promise.reject(error);
});
```